# Workflow - all picklist values are not adding

Tags: visual-workflow, developer-console, workbench, developer-org

I'm trying to add some picklist values from a field but all picklist values are not adding.Kindly please check the condition once and any ideas please share .

### Rule Criteria:

Case: Status EQUALS Closed AND Case: Case Record Type EQUALS(adding 17 picklist values) but only few are adding to the condition from record type field.

I can able to select 17 picklist values but after saving the workflow rule only few values are adding to the condition.

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the lens icon, it allows you to select all the picklist values but since the field(where selected values get populated) is a text field, it has the number of characters limit and it automatically truncates the additional characters.

You have to select a few options at a time and the same condition to be added again to select the remaining options combined with an OR condition say
`Case Record Type EQUALS Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5  OR Case Record Type EQUALS Test6,Test7,Test8,Test9` and so on.